# How can I find the svn diff between working copy and arbitrary rev?

Tags: linux, svn, command-line, diff

I'm trying to write a multi-file patch for an open-source project, but the master copy has changed since I started working. I need to get the SVN difference (just the files under version control) between my uncommitted version and the revision from which it was checked. Which SVN command can I use to find the difference?

**Edit:** I'm sorry, I must have been using the term "working copy" improperly. I need to compare my uncommitted changes to the revision off which they are based. In other words, I checked out revision 1000 and changed files `foo` and `bar`. The rev number is now up to 1015, but I need to compare my version of `foo` and `bar` to the version of revision 1000. Is there an easy command to do this (compare my altered copy of a program with a past revision)?

Comment: I believe that you used the term "working copy" correctly. When you check out rev 1000 then you working copy is copy of rev 1000. It doesn't really matter that the base is 1015. You just have to specify the N (which is normally base) to be 1000 as pretty much all the commands defaults to base. So svn diff -r1000 should work perfectly for you (supposing you really checked out the rev 1000). If you check the diff itself it does say what revision did it compare (as ezpz showed in his answer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use -rN:M parameter with diff command which specifies the revisions you want to compare. Just provide revision from which your working copy was checked out (you can omit M as it defaults to working copy) and you should get what you need.

If you don't remember the original revision number try to run `svn status -v` and first column should show it.

More info `svn help diff`...

Answer (score 9):

`svn diff` takes a `-rN:M` argument which defaults to `N == BASE` and `M == working copy`. Will `svn diff -r REV` where `REV` is the revision you want not work?

To answer your edit, suppose you have the following:

```
$ ls
foo bar baz
$ svn st -u
Status against revision:    1071
$ echo "more stuff" >> foo
$ svn diff -r 1000 foo
Index: foo
===================================================================
--- foo  (revision 1000)
+++ foo  (working copy)
...
```

I believe this is what you are after, yes?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal was to get a report of just the filenames where the contents has changed, this should do the trick:

```
svn diff | grep 'Index: ' .
```